how to draw horizontal hi low range with background color every Quadruple (Quad) Witching Friday in pine script
I want to draw hi low range of every Quadruple witching" refers to the simultaneous expiration four times a year of stock options, index futures, and index futures options derivatives contracts. The fourth type of contract involved in quadruple witching, single-stock futures, hasn't traded in the U.S. since 2020 and was never a major contributor to equity trading volumes.
What is now effectively "triple witching" occurs on the third Friday of March, June, September, and December.
Please give idea for to plot Quadruple witching dates hi low range with background color that extend to left
in pine script

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
